# Swift 3: Cannot remove duplicate data from the tableView

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift3, duplicates

I am trying to remove duplicates from the tableView. The data that are fetched on the tableview comes from external database. Some of the data that are fetched are repeated few times.

The data that I need to be displayed is the profile name and region i.e. Show All, North, East, South, West. Now, there can be a profile (For E.g. George's Concreting) that can appear in  3 regions. For instance North, East and West. By default, when the view loads, it shows all the businesses in all regions. On this view, I have some businesses that are repeated. Our George's Concreting profile repeats 3 times in this view, where it should only be repeated once. When I click on North/East/West the George's Concreting should appear there as well just once.

So basically, George's Concreting should only appear once in Show All although it has 3 businesses in 3 regions and when we click on the other regions, it should also appear once. Please refer to the screenshot.

Using the following code I get and error on Line, Please refer to ****error****

coding:

```
class StorageSubCatagoriezTwo
{
    var nameString:String
    var idString:String
    var address:String
    var telephone:String
    var email:String
    var website:String

init(tempName:String,tempID:String,tempaddress:String,tempTelephone:String,tempEmail:String,tempWebsite:String)
{
    self.nameString = tempName.trimmingCharacters(in:  CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    self.idString  = tempID.trimmingCharacters(in:  CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    self.address = tempaddress.trimmingCharacters(in:  CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    self.telephone = tempTelephone.trimmingCharacters(in:  CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    self.email = tempEmail.trimmingCharacters(in:  CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    self.website = tempWebsite.trimmingCharacters(in:  CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
}
}

class StorageSubCatagoriezTwoNorth
{
    var nameString:String
    var idString:String
    var address:String
    var telephone:String
    var email:String
    var website:String

init(tempName:String,tempID:String,tempaddress:String,tempTelephone:String,tempEmail:String,tempWebsite:String)
{
    self.nameString = tempName.trimmingCharacters(in:  CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    self.idString  = tempID.trimmingCharacters(in:  CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    self.address = tempaddress.trimmingCharacters(in:  CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    self.telephone = tempTelephone.trimmingCharacters(in:  CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    self.email = tempEmail.trimmingCharacters(in:  CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    self.website = tempWebsite.trimmingCharacters(in:  CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
}
}

class StorageSubCatagoriezTwoEast
{
    var nameString:String
    var idString:String
    var address:String
    var telephone:String
    var email:String
    var website:String

init(tempName:String,tempID:String,tempaddress:String,tempTelephone:String,tempEmail:String,tempWebsite:String)
{
    self.nameString = tempName.trimmingCharacters(in:  CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    self.idString  = tempID.trimmingCharacters(in:  CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    self.address = tempaddress.trimmingCharacters(in:  CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    self.telephone = tempTelephone.trimmingCharacters(in:  CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    self.email = tempEmail.trimmingCharacters(in:  CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    self.website = tempWebsite.trimmingCharacters(in:  CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
}
}

class StorageSubCatagoriezTwoWest
{
    var nameString:String
    var idString:String
    var address:String
    var telephone:String
    var email:String
    var website:String

init(tempName:String,tempID:String,tempaddress:String,tempTelephone:String,tempEmail:String,tempWebsite:String)
{
    self.nameString = tempName.trimmingCharacters(in:  CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    self.idString  = tempID.trimmingCharacters(in:  CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    self.address = tempaddress.trimmingCharacters(in:  CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    self.telephone = tempTelephone.trimmingCharacters(in:  CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    self.email = tempEmail.trimmingCharacters(in:  CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    self.website = tempWebsite.trimmingCharacters(in:  CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)    }
}

class StorageSubCatagoriezTwoSouth
{
    var nameString:String
    var idString:String
    var address:String
    var telephone:String
    var email:String
    var website:String

init(tempName:String,tempID:String,tempaddress:String,tempTelephone:String,tempEmail:String,tempWebsite:String)
{
    self.nameString = tempName.trimmingCharacters(in:  CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    self.idString  = tempID.trimmingCharacters(in:  CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    self.address = tempaddress.trimmingCharacters(in:  CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    self.telephone = tempTelephone.trimmingCharacters(in:  CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    self.email = tempEmail.trimmingCharacters(in:  CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    self.website = tempWebsite.trimmingCharacters(in:  CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
}
}

___________________________________________________________




 var subCatagorizeDataTwo = Array<StorageSubCatagoriezTwo>()
var subCatagorizeDataTwoN = Array<StorageSubCatagoriezTwoNorth>()
var subCatagorizeDataTwoE = Array<StorageSubCatagoriezTwoEast>()
var subCatagorizeDataTwoW = Array<StorageSubCatagoriezTwoWest>()
var subCatagorizeDataTwoS = Array<StorageSubCatagoriezTwoSouth>()
var SubCatagoriez3rd = Array<StorageSubCatagoriez3rd>()



func removeDuplicate (sourceArray: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    var uniqueArray:[Int] = []
    for object in sourceArray {
        if !uniqueArray.contains(object)
        {
            uniqueArray.append(object)
        }
    }
    return uniqueArray
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {



    if indexPath.section == 0
    {
        let cell = self.bussinessTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "bussinessCell", for: indexPath) as! BussinessCell

        let tableObjects:StorageSubCatagoriezTwo = subCatagorizeDataTwo[indexPath.row]

        //let charCheck = (tableObjects.address).replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")


        if reg == "North"
        {
            cell.bussinessName.text = " "
            cell.addLabel.text = " "
            cell.telLabel.text = " "
            cell.emailLabel.text =  " "
            cell.webLabel.text = " "

            var tableObjects:StorageSubCatagoriezTwoNorth = subCatagorizeDataTwoN[indexPath.row]
            tableObjects = removeDuplicate(sourceArray: [tableObjects.nameString]) 
//**error** {Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected element type 'Int'}


            if tableObjects.address.characters.isEmpty != true
            {
                cell.addLabel.text = tableObjects.address
            }
            else
            {
                //nothing
            }
            if tableObjects.telephone.characters.isEmpty != true
            {
                cell.telLabel.text = tableObjects.telephone
            }
            else
            {

            }
            if tableObjects.email.characters.isEmpty != true
            {
                cell.emailLabel.text = tableObjects.email
            }
            else
            {

            }
            if tableObjects.website.characters.isEmpty != true{
                cell.webLabel.text = tableObjects.website
            }
            else{

            }
        }
        else if reg == "East"
        {
            cell.bussinessName.text = " "
            let tableObjects:StorageSubCatagoriezTwoEast = subCatagorizeDataTwoE[indexPath.row]
            cell.bussinessName.text = tableObjects.nameString
            if tableObjects.address.characters.isEmpty != true
            {
                cell.addLabel.text = tableObjects.address
            }
            else
            {
                //nothing
            }
            if tableObjects.telephone.characters.isEmpty != true
            {
                cell.telLabel.text = tableObjects.telephone
            }
            else
            {

            }
            if tableObjects.email.characters.isEmpty != true
            {
                cell.emailLabel.text = tableObjects.email
            }
            else
            {

            }
            if tableObjects.website.characters.isEmpty != true
            {
                cell.webLabel.text = tableObjects.website
            }
            else{

            }
        }
        else if reg == "South"
        {
            cell.bussinessName.text = " "
            let tableObjects:StorageSubCatagoriezTwoSouth = subCatagorizeDataTwoS[indexPath.row]
            cell.bussinessName.text = tableObjects.nameString
            if tableObjects.address.characters.isEmpty != true
            {
                cell.addLabel.text = tableObjects.address
            }
            else
            {
                //nothing
            }
            if tableObjects.telephone.characters.isEmpty != true
            {
                cell.telLabel.text = tableObjects.telephone
            }
            else
            {

            }
            if tableObjects.email.characters.isEmpty != true
            {
                cell.emailLabel.text = tableObjects.email
            }
            else
            {

            }
            if tableObjects.website.characters.isEmpty != true{
                cell.webLabel.text = tableObjects.website
            }
            else{

            }
        }
        else if reg == "West"
        {
            cell.bussinessName.text = " "
            let tableObjects:StorageSubCatagoriezTwoWest = subCatagorizeDataTwoW[indexPath.row]
            cell.bussinessName.text = tableObjects.nameString
            if tableObjects.address.characters.isEmpty != true
            {
              cell.addLabel.text = tableObjects.address
            }
            else
            {
                //nothing
            }
            if tableObjects.telephone.characters.isEmpty != true
            {
                cell.telLabel.text = tableObjects.telephone
            }
            else
            {

            }
            if tableObjects.email.characters.isEmpty != true
            {
                cell.emailLabel.text = tableObjects.email
            }
            else
            {

            }
            if tableObjects.website.characters.isEmpty != true{
               cell.webLabel.text = tableObjects.website
            }

        }
        else{
            let tableObjects:StorageSubCatagoriezTwo = subCatagorizeDataTwo[indexPath.row]
            cell.bussinessName.text = tableObjects.nameString

            let charCheck = (tableObjects.address).replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")

            cell.bussinessName.text = tableObjects.nameString
            cell.addLabel.text = tableObjects.address
            cell.telLabel.text = tableObjects.telephone
            cell.emailLabel.text = tableObjects.email
            cell.webLabel.text = tableObjects.website

        }


        return cell
    }

    else if indexPath.section == 1
    {
        let cell = self.bussinessTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "bussinessCell2")
        cell?.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center
        switch regId
        {
        case 0:
            if subCatagorizeDataTwo.count != forAll
            {
                cell?.textLabel?.text = "Load More Data"
                cell?.textLabel?.textColor = Color.whiteColor
                cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray

            }else{
                cell?.textLabel?.text = "No More Data Found"
                cell?.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.darkGray
                cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
                cell?.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none
            }
        case 1:
            if subCatagorizeDataTwoN.count != forN
            {
                cell?.textLabel?.text = "Load More Data"
                cell?.textLabel?.textColor = Color.whiteColor
                cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray

            }else{
                cell?.textLabel?.text = "No More Data Found"
                cell?.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.darkGray
                cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
                cell?.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none
            }
        case 2:
            if subCatagorizeDataTwoE.count != forE
            {
                cell?.textLabel?.text = "Load More Data"
                cell?.textLabel?.textColor = Color.whiteColor
                cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray

            }else{
                cell?.textLabel?.text = "No More Data Found"
                cell?.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.darkGray
                cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
                cell?.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none
            }
        case 3:
            if subCatagorizeDataTwoS.count != forS
            {
                cell?.textLabel?.text = "Load More Data"
                cell?.textLabel?.textColor = Color.whiteColor
                cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray

            }else{
                cell?.textLabel?.text = "No More Data Found"
                cell?.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.darkGray
                cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
                cell?.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none
            }
        case 4:
            if subCatagorizeDataTwoW.count != forW
            {
                cell?.textLabel?.text = "Load More Data"
                cell?.textLabel?.textColor = Color.whiteColor
                cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray

            }else{
                cell?.textLabel?.text = "No More Data Found"
                cell?.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.darkGray
                cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
                cell?.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none
            }

        default:break
        }

        return cell!
    }
    else
    {
        let tableObjects:StorageSubCatagoriez3rd = SubCatagoriez3rd[indexPath.row]
        let cell = self.bussinessTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "bussinessCell3")
        cell?.textLabel?.text = tableObjects.nameString
        return cell!

    }
}
```

Screenshot [image]

Comment: your func removeDuplicate is looking for an array of INT's, but you are passing into it a string.

Comment: I tried using as [String], but then I get this error "Cannot assign value of type '[String]' to type 'StorageSubCatagoriezTwoNorth'

Comment: what is StorageSubCat...?

Comment: hi, I have updated my code above

Comment: Are these StorageSubCats classes?  Whatever makes up these arrays needs to be passed into your func.  They look as if they have more data than just ints.

Comment: I am new to this and my coding skills are poor. How can I pass them?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151654/discussion-between-sarah-malik-and-douglas).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:** *( I only created the 4 funcs)

```
  func  UpdateSubCatagorizeTwoRegNorth(_ id:String) {
    subCatagorizeDataTwo.removeAll()
    subCatagorizeDataTwoN.removeAll()
    subCatagorizeDataTwoE.removeAll()
    subCatagorizeDataTwoW.removeAll()
    subCatagorizeDataTwoS.removeAll()
    SubCatagoriez3rd.removeAll()
    self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    progress.isHidden = false

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: urls.subCatagoriezTwoURLRegNorth as URL)
    let postString = "id="+id
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { data,response,error in
        guard error == nil && data != nil else
        {
            self.progress.isHidden = true
            self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            self.alertMessage.alert("Error:\(error)", icon: "error", View: self)
            return
        }

        let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse

        if httpStatus!.statusCode == 200
        {
            if data?.count != 0
            {
                let responseString = convert.contvertToDictionary(data!) as? [[String:AnyObject]]

                if responseString != nil
                {
                    for dictionary in responseString!
                    {

                        let id = String(describing: dictionary["id"]!)
                        let name = String(describing: dictionary["BUSINESS_NAME"]!)
                        let email = String(describing: dictionary["EMAIL"]!)
                        var streetNo = String(describing: dictionary["STREET_NO"]!)
                        var streetName = String(describing: dictionary["STREET_NAME"]!)
                        var suburbID = String(describing: dictionary["SUBURB_ID"]!)
                        var postCode = String(describing: dictionary["POSTCODE"]!)
                        // let regionID = String(describing: dictionary["REGION_ID"]!)
                        let region = String(describing: dictionary["region"]!)
                        var landline = String(describing: dictionary["PHONE_FIXED"]!)
                        var mobile = String(describing: dictionary["PHONE_MOBILE"]!)
                        let website = String(describing: dictionary["WEBURL"]!)
                        var suburbName = String(describing: dictionary["Suburb"]!)
                        let streedNoHide = String(describing: dictionary["STREET_NO_HIDDEN"]!)
                        let streetNameHide = String(describing: dictionary["STREET_NAME_HIDDEN"]!)
                        let suburbHide = String(describing: dictionary["SUBURB_HIDDEN"]!)
                        let postCodeHide = String(describing: dictionary["POSTCODE_HIDDEN"]!)
                        let mobileHide = String(describing: dictionary["PHONE_MOBILE_HIDDEN"]!)
                        let landlineHide = String(describing: dictionary["PHONE_FIXED_HIDDEN"]!)

                        if streedNoHide != "0"
                        {
                            streetNo = ""
                        }else{

                        }

                        if streetNameHide != "0"
                        {
                            streetName=""
                        }
                        else{
                            //nothing here
                        }


                        if suburbHide != "0"
                        {
                            suburbName = ""
                            suburbID = ""
                        }
                        else{
                            //nothing here
                        }


                        if postCodeHide != "0"
                        {
                            postCode = ""
                        }
                        else{
                            //nothing here
                        }

                        if mobileHide != "0"
                        {
                            mobile = ""
                        }
                        else{
                            //nothing here
                        }
                        if landlineHide != "0"
                        {
                            landline = ""
                        }else
                        {

                        }
                        // streetno
                        DispatchQueue.main.async
                            {

                                if region == "North"
                                {
                                    self.subCatagorizeDataTwoN.append(StorageSubCatagoriezTwoNorth(tempName: name, tempID: id, tempaddress: " "+streetNo+" "+streetName+" "+suburbName+" "+postCode, tempTelephone: landline+" "+mobile, tempEmail: email, tempWebsite: website))
                                }
                                self.subCatagorizeDataTwo.append(StorageSubCatagoriezTwo(tempName: name, tempID: id, tempaddress:  " "+streetNo+" "+streetName+" "+suburbName+" "+postCode, tempTelephone: landline+" "+mobile, tempEmail: email, tempWebsite: website))
                        }

                    }

                    DispatchQueue.main.async
                        {

                            if  self.subCatagorizeDataTwoN.count >= 10
                            {
                                self.forN = 10
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                self.forN = self.subCatagorizeDataTwoN.count
                            }

                            self.UpdateSubCatagorizeTwo1(self.catName, url: self.urls.XRef)
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async
                        {
                            self.progress.isHidden = true
                            self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                            self.alertMessage.alert("Problem with Requesting! Error 404", icon: "error", View: self)
                    }
                }

            }
            else
            {
                DispatchQueue.main.async
                    {
                        self.progress.isHidden = true
                        self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                        self.alertMessage.alert("No data got from url!", icon: "error", View: self)
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            DispatchQueue.main.async
                {
                    self.progress.isHidden = true
                    self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                    self.alertMessage.alert("error httpstatus code is : \(httpStatus!.statusCode)", icon: "error", View: self)
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()


}

func  UpdateSubCatagorizeTwoRegEast(_ id:String) {
    subCatagorizeDataTwo.removeAll()
    subCatagorizeDataTwoN.removeAll()
    subCatagorizeDataTwoE.removeAll()
    subCatagorizeDataTwoW.removeAll()
    subCatagorizeDataTwoS.removeAll()
    SubCatagoriez3rd.removeAll()
    self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    progress.isHidden = false

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: urls.subCatagoriezTwoURLEast as URL)
    let postString = "id="+id
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { data,response,error in
        guard error == nil && data != nil else
        {
            self.progress.isHidden = true
            self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            self.alertMessage.alert("Error:\(error)", icon: "error", View: self)
            return
        }

        let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse

        if httpStatus!.statusCode == 200
        {
            if data?.count != 0
            {
                let responseString = convert.contvertToDictionary(data!) as? [[String:AnyObject]]

                if responseString != nil
                {
                    for dictionary in responseString!
                    {

                        let id = String(describing: dictionary["id"]!)
                        let name = String(describing: dictionary["BUSINESS_NAME"]!)
                        let email = String(describing: dictionary["EMAIL"]!)
                        var streetNo = String(describing: dictionary["STREET_NO"]!)
                        var streetName = String(describing: dictionary["STREET_NAME"]!)
                        var suburbID = String(describing: dictionary["SUBURB_ID"]!)
                        var postCode = String(describing: dictionary["POSTCODE"]!)
                        // let regionID = String(describing: dictionary["REGION_ID"]!)
                        let region = String(describing: dictionary["region"]!)
                        var landline = String(describing: dictionary["PHONE_FIXED"]!)
                        var mobile = String(describing: dictionary["PHONE_MOBILE"]!)
                        let website = String(describing: dictionary["WEBURL"]!)
                        var suburbName = String(describing: dictionary["Suburb"]!)
                        let streedNoHide = String(describing: dictionary["STREET_NO_HIDDEN"]!)
                        let streetNameHide = String(describing: dictionary["STREET_NAME_HIDDEN"]!)
                        let suburbHide = String(describing: dictionary["SUBURB_HIDDEN"]!)
                        let postCodeHide = String(describing: dictionary["POSTCODE_HIDDEN"]!)
                        let mobileHide = String(describing: dictionary["PHONE_MOBILE_HIDDEN"]!)
                        let landlineHide = String(describing: dictionary["PHONE_FIXED_HIDDEN"]!)

                        if streedNoHide != "0"
                        {
                            streetNo = ""
                        }else{

                        }

                        if streetNameHide != "0"
                        {
                            streetName=""
                        }
                        else{
                            //nothing here
                        }


                        if suburbHide != "0"
                        {
                            suburbName = ""
                            suburbID = ""
                        }
                        else{
                            //nothing here
                        }


                        if postCodeHide != "0"
                        {
                            postCode = ""
                        }
                        else{
                            //nothing here
                        }

                        if mobileHide != "0"
                        {
                            mobile = ""
                        }
                        else{
                            //nothing here
                        }
                        if landlineHide != "0"
                        {
                            landline = ""
                        }else
                        {

                        }
                        // streetno
                        DispatchQueue.main.async
                            {

                                if region == "East"
                                {
                                    self.subCatagorizeDataTwoE.append(StorageSubCatagoriezTwoEast(tempName: name, tempID: id, tempaddress: " "+streetNo+" "+streetName+" "+suburbName+" "+postCode, tempTelephone: landline+" "+mobile, tempEmail: email, tempWebsite: website))
                                }
                                self.subCatagorizeDataTwo.append(StorageSubCatagoriezTwo(tempName: name, tempID: id, tempaddress:  " "+streetNo+" "+streetName+" "+suburbName+" "+postCode, tempTelephone: landline+" "+mobile, tempEmail: email, tempWebsite: website))
                        }

                    }

                    DispatchQueue.main.async
                        {

                            if  self.subCatagorizeDataTwoE.count >= 10
                            {
                                self.forE = 10
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                self.forE = self.subCatagorizeDataTwoE.count
                            }

                            self.UpdateSubCatagorizeTwo1(self.catName, url: self.urls.XRef)
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async
                        {
                            self.progress.isHidden = true
                            self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                            self.alertMessage.alert("Problem with Requesting! Error 404", icon: "error", View: self)
                    }
                }

            }
            else
            {
                DispatchQueue.main.async
                    {
                        self.progress.isHidden = true
                        self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                        self.alertMessage.alert("No data got from url!", icon: "error", View: self)
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            DispatchQueue.main.async
                {
                    self.progress.isHidden = true
                    self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                    self.alertMessage.alert("error httpstatus code is : \(httpStatus!.statusCode)", icon: "error", View: self)
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()


}

func  UpdateSubCatagorizeTwoRegSouth(_ id:String) {
    subCatagorizeDataTwo.removeAll()
    subCatagorizeDataTwoN.removeAll()
    subCatagorizeDataTwoE.removeAll()
    subCatagorizeDataTwoW.removeAll()
    subCatagorizeDataTwoS.removeAll()
    SubCatagoriez3rd.removeAll()
    self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    progress.isHidden = false

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: urls.subCatagoriezTwoURLRegSouth as URL)
    let postString = "id="+id
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { data,response,error in
        guard error == nil && data != nil else
        {
            self.progress.isHidden = true
            self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            self.alertMessage.alert("Error:\(error)", icon: "error", View: self)
            return
        }

        let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse

        if httpStatus!.statusCode == 200
        {
            if data?.count != 0
            {
                let responseString = convert.contvertToDictionary(data!) as? [[String:AnyObject]]

                if responseString != nil
                {
                    for dictionary in responseString!
                    {

                        let id = String(describing: dictionary["id"]!)
                        let name = String(describing: dictionary["BUSINESS_NAME"]!)
                        let email = String(describing: dictionary["EMAIL"]!)
                        var streetNo = String(describing: dictionary["STREET_NO"]!)
                        var streetName = String(describing: dictionary["STREET_NAME"]!)
                        var suburbID = String(describing: dictionary["SUBURB_ID"]!)
                        var postCode = String(describing: dictionary["POSTCODE"]!)
                        // let regionID = String(describing: dictionary["REGION_ID"]!)
                        let region = String(describing: dictionary["region"]!)
                        var landline = String(describing: dictionary["PHONE_FIXED"]!)
                        var mobile = String(describing: dictionary["PHONE_MOBILE"]!)
                        let website = String(describing: dictionary["WEBURL"]!)
                        var suburbName = String(describing: dictionary["Suburb"]!)
                        let streedNoHide = String(describing: dictionary["STREET_NO_HIDDEN"]!)
                        let streetNameHide = String(describing: dictionary["STREET_NAME_HIDDEN"]!)
                        let suburbHide = String(describing: dictionary["SUBURB_HIDDEN"]!)
                        let postCodeHide = String(describing: dictionary["POSTCODE_HIDDEN"]!)
                        let mobileHide = String(describing: dictionary["PHONE_MOBILE_HIDDEN"]!)
                        let landlineHide = String(describing: dictionary["PHONE_FIXED_HIDDEN"]!)

                        if streedNoHide != "0"
                        {
                            streetNo = ""
                        }else{

                        }

                        if streetNameHide != "0"
                        {
                            streetName=""
                        }
                        else{
                            //nothing here
                        }


                        if suburbHide != "0"
                        {
                            suburbName = ""
                            suburbID = ""
                        }
                        else{
                            //nothing here
                        }


                        if postCodeHide != "0"
                        {
                            postCode = ""
                        }
                        else{
                            //nothing here
                        }

                        if mobileHide != "0"
                        {
                            mobile = ""
                        }
                        else{
                            //nothing here
                        }
                        if landlineHide != "0"
                        {
                            landline = ""
                        }else
                        {

                        }
                        // streetno
                        DispatchQueue.main.async
                            {

                                if region == "South"
                                {
                                    self.subCatagorizeDataTwoS.append(StorageSubCatagoriezTwoSouth(tempName: name, tempID: id, tempaddress: " "+streetNo+" "+streetName+" "+suburbName+" "+postCode, tempTelephone: landline+" "+mobile, tempEmail: email, tempWebsite: website))
                                }

                                self.subCatagorizeDataTwo.append(StorageSubCatagoriezTwo(tempName: name, tempID: id, tempaddress:  " "+streetNo+" "+streetName+" "+suburbName+" "+postCode, tempTelephone: landline+" "+mobile, tempEmail: email, tempWebsite: website))
                        }

                    }

                    DispatchQueue.main.async
                        {

                            if  self.subCatagorizeDataTwoS.count >= 10
                            {
                                self.forS = 10
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                self.forS = self.subCatagorizeDataTwoS.count
                            }

                            self.UpdateSubCatagorizeTwo1(self.catName, url: self.urls.XRef)
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async
                        {
                            self.progress.isHidden = true
                            self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                            self.alertMessage.alert("Problem with Requesting! Error 404", icon: "error", View: self)
                    }
                }

            }
            else
            {
                DispatchQueue.main.async
                    {
                        self.progress.isHidden = true
                        self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                        self.alertMessage.alert("No data got from url!", icon: "error", View: self)
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            DispatchQueue.main.async
                {
                    self.progress.isHidden = true
                    self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                    self.alertMessage.alert("error httpstatus code is : \(httpStatus!.statusCode)", icon: "error", View: self)
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()


}
```

Please do the same thing for WEST region. and replace required.